# структура проекта pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, архитектура

десткоп приложение на pyqt5, управление персоналом автотранспортного предприятия, не могу определится структурой приложения, приложение многостраничное, допускается ли запросы в базу данных в части UI. благодарю !

Comment: ну по любому предполагается введение базы сотрудников, табеля, заявок от персонала и обработку заявлений. Если попробовать отталкиваться от этого, то можно сообразить всё это на составные части, а дальше соображать функционал и связывать всё это. А часть запросов в бд и вывода в UI лучше разделять, чтобы не нагромождать, аля бэк и фронт вашего приложения. Следовательно один модуль у вас для обработки UI моментов, один бэк, а за бэком функции запросов в базу с возвратом данных удобоваримых. Для дальнейшей консультации можете чекануть мне в ТГ в профиле

Comment: в qt запросы в БД разрешены в потоке в котором БД была открыта